# How do i get menu from this array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, alamofire

So I have this `JSON` data [Link](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ctSvrAVwoi?indent=2) and i want to get menu items from it, I'm using **Alamofire** swift. I have tried this.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url!, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = response.result

        if response.result.isSuccess{
            let jsonObj = JSON(result.value!)

            if let ff = jsonObj["Items"]["Menus"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
                print(ff)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Items` contain `Array` not `Dictionary`, so you need to access its first object like this.

```
 if let ff = jsonObj["Items"][0]["Menu"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
     print(ff)
 }
```

**Edit:** Try to get separate object from `jsonObj`

```
let jsonDic = jsonObj as! [String: AnyObject]
if let items = jsonDic["Items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] { 
    if let menu = items[0]["Menu"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        print(menu)
    }
}
```

**Note:** The key is `Menu` not `Menus`.

Comment: Am not getting anything printed

Comment: Have you changed `Menus` with `Menu`

Comment: why `Stringg` with 2g ?

Comment: Sorry by mistake set as array, check this line `if let menu = items[0]["Menu"] as? [String: AnyObject] {` it will be corrected with dictionary now

Comment: I'd suggest using `guard let` instead of `if let`. Also, you can chain multiple `let`s into the same `if`/`guard` statement. For instance, `guard let items = jsonDic["Items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]], menu = items[0]["Menu"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {return}`